# hide and show button when check box clicked

Tags: android, eclipse

i want code en eclipse android when i clicked checkbox i want to show hidden button 
i'm beginner in android so please help me :(

this is my xml code :

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/CB1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:fontFamily="Segoe UI"
    android:text="I Want To Select A Favorite Station And Receive Notification."
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.CB1);
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
@Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);//TO HIDE THE BUTTON
btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);//TO SHOW THE BUTTON
    }
});
```

where btn is your button.

Comment: Will this code be suitable if my button is on different activity??Because the button which i need to hide and show is on different activity I really dont no what I am supposed to do 
 kindly help,

Comment: Create a shared preference.If the checkbox is clicked then store a flag as true else false.When you are back in your activity that contains the button,check for the flag.If it is true then hide it,else show

Answer (score 0):

Reference the checkbox in your Activity and set an OnCheckedChangeListener:

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.CB1);
checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
@Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

    // do whatever

    }
});
```

Comment: thanks , its works ... nut how i can hide and show the button or the spinner , or make it visible ?

Comment: Check this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)

Comment: Hi If my button which i need to hide and show is on different activity what should i do?